# Javascript - Find <a> tag, where href attribute contains a string, prevent default event and override

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having this code right now, which works just fine with  links with an ID.

```js
 var buttonclick = document.getElementById("myLink");
    buttonclick.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); window.location = 'facebook.com'
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="google.com" id="myLink">google</a>
```

What I want to do is get all links without an ID, just the ones which contain the world 'google' in the href attribute, and apply the same events further in my original code.

I have tried combining with jQuery, and all I managed to do is:

```
$('a[href*="google"]')
```

I am not sure how to combine it with the code above. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$('a[href*="google"]').on("click", functionName)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`document.querySelector(selector)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector),

```
var buttonclick = document.querySelector('a[href*="google"]');
buttonclick.addEventListener("click", function(event){
   event.preventDefault(); 
   window.location = 'facebook.com'
});
```

If you want to target all the elements matches the selector then just use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead of `querySelector`.

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="google"]').forEach(function(button){
  button.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    window.location = 'facebook.com'
  });
});
```

Edited to use the function `forEach` belongs to nodeList object. It was inspired from @rory's answer.

Comment: Should you not define 1 function and then assign it to all click events?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a `click()` handler in your jQuery code. Try this:

```
$('a[href*="google"]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  window.location.assign('http://facebook.com');
});
```

If you'd prefer to stick with plain JS, then you can use `querySelectorAll()`, like this:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorll('a[href*="google"]'), function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.assign('http://facebook.com');
  });
});
```

Comment: This has worked for one link, which is already good. Thank you for that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am not aware that `nodeList` have a function called `forEach`.

Comment: It does, but it doesn't have support in IE. I updated it to a more reliable cross-browser version